# How to save an HTML file with fastcoloredtextbox.dll component?

Tags: c#, html, windows, components

i'm developing an HTML editor in C# with the [FastColoredTextBox.dll](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) component. I have the code for the "Save As" option. But when the file is saved, and i tried pressing the Save As option again, the SaveFileDialog will come up. I wanted it to save to the file that we saved earlier. Here's the Save As code:

```
 private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = default(SaveFileDialog);
        if (FastColoredTextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "HTML Files|.html|" + "All Files|*.*";

            sfd.DefaultExt = "html";

            sfd.ShowDialog();


            string location = null;
            string sourcecode = FastColoredTextBox1.Text;
            location = sfd.FileName;
            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(sfd.FileName, ""))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(location, false))
                {
                    writer.Write(sourcecode);
                    writer.Dispose();
                    this.Text = "Netplait 2.5.1 - " + System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(location);
                }
            }
        }
        if (Directory.Exists(sfd.FileName) == true)
        {
            string location = sfd.InitialDirectory;
            File.WriteAllText(location, (FastColoredTextBox1.Text));
        }
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with fast colored text box component. You need to store off the path and not show the dialog again. Store the path in a class variable and check if it's got a value before your first if statement. If it does then save to that path, otherwise do what you do now. As it stands you have no logic to check if you've saved once before. Instead you just always show the save dialog. Also: don't use ReferenceEquals to check string equality. Use string.Equals or ==. You also don't need to call Dispose on your writer since it's in a using block.

Answer (score 1):

I must say, this code seems a bit chaotic to me.

Why not just create the dialog instead?

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = default(SaveFileDialog);
```

And this, why not just check `sfd.FileName != ""` or better `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(sfd.FileName)`

```
if (!object.ReferenceEquals(sfd.FileName, ""))
```

Am I mistaken, that `sfd.FileName` should return a file name, not a directory?
Because then this code does not make sense:

```
 if (Directory.Exists(sfd.FileName) == true)
```

Anyway, before opening the dialog, you can set `sfd.InitialDirectory` and `sfd.FileName` as per documentation

[SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's still not what i'm looking for.

Comment: I am sorry I could not be of much help. I thought that you wanted to open the dialog with the same path as before, but I guess not.

Comment: It's ok, i got a little tip there.